# Catching a word with re.findall

Tags: python, regex, find

I'm trying to build a dictionary with Names:IDs from a web page that have a list of accounts. For each account the HTML code looks like this:

```
<a href="javascript:UserWindow('Mike','14','0','27s', 'profile')">
<a href="user.php?id=14">Mike</a>
```

The python code that I've build:

```
IDs = re.findall('(?<=user.php\?id=\")\w+(?=\">)', src)
names = re.findall('(?<=UserWindow\(\')\w+(?=\',\')', src)
```

For the names works perfectly but for IDs it doesnt work and I don't know to do it. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't the second param of `UserWindow()` the ID?

Comment: @Casimir yes, the second one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `id` doesn't seem to start with `"`. So, use this

```
IDs = re.findall('(?<=user.php\?id=)\w+(?=\">)', src)
```

Comment: Yes, I don't know what was in my mind :( I looked like 1000 times over the code and every time I saw the quotes . Thanks

Comment: Can you help further more: It seems that in this way: I have a Name, but the ID it isn't for the right account. For example: Mike has ID 11 instead of 14. How can I fix this?

Comment: @MikeT I believe that should be a separate question. :)

Answer (score 0):

An other way using finditer:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re

html = '''<a href="javascript:UserWindow('Mike','14','0','27s', 'profile')">
<a href="javascript:UserWindow('Dorothee','184','0','27s', 'profile')">
<a href="javascript:UserWindow('Esmeralda','7','0','27s', 'profile')">
<a href="javascript:UserWindow('Monique','16','0','27s', 'profile')">'''

pattern = r'UserWindow\(\'([^\']+)\',\'([^\']+)'

users = {}

matches = re.finditer(pattern, html)

for m in matches:
    users[m.group(1)] = m.group(2)

print users
```